# SQL Server : string or binary data would be truncated, column length is long enough

Tags: sql, sql-server

The column type is `nvarchar(200)`, but I get an error when I want to update a value with length of 99 characters. I found a lot of answers on the web, all of them saying "increase the column width", but as mentioned, it is already on `200` and I changed it to `max`, but still the same error. I am 100% sure I am using the correct database and correct column. Why is it not allowing me to add a `string` with length of 99 characters to a column with length of `200`?

Screenshots:

- Query:

[image]

- Column property:

[image]

- Query confirming column length

[image]

Comment: Is the column declared as a `varchar()` or `nvarchar()`?

Comment: It is declared as `nvarchar(200)`

Comment: Your error message says "procedure UPDATE_Prospect", make sure that this is the operation thats throwing the error. Also check triggers linked to the table.

Comment: @EzLo when I change the string value to say 92 characters, it updates the entry successfully. So it's definitely the length of the string that's causing the error

Comment: @deanwilliammills my money is on a trigger.

Comment: @EzLo Your the man. Rookie mistake, someone added a trigger that does an insert into another table, that table's column is to short. Thank you very much!!!! After 2 hours it's working now.